# SQL Server Extended events vs DMVs

Tags: sql-server

From what I have gathered so far, DMVs provide info that an Extended Event would provide. From a server health monitoring perspective, why can't I use relevant DMV queries that I schedule to run on some timely manner as opposed to using Extended Event Sessions.

Comment: DMVs provide only a fraction of the information Extended Events provide plus traces can keep historical information too. Personally, I used both.

Answer (score 2):

Most DMV provide realtime or active transaction status and the information they provide can sometimes get flushed under certain situations (like a server restart). while extended events record events into a physical xel file which can be accessed later. If your intention is to just check realtime situation for s sql server then you can schedule dmv at specific times per day. If you want to perform a root cause analysis and understand at what time a certain issue occurred and when it ended, then extended events are the best place to start looking from.